# Android emulator reads at script as a text file

Tags: android, jquery, asp-classic

i have a server side page that i load with in my page with jquery. the funny this is it works fine on chrome's ripple emulator and on web browsers but android's emulator reads the script like a text file. it's not able to executed the script. here's the script:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<!--#include file="Connections/tv.asp" -->
<%
Dim rs_read__MMColParam
rs_read__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("news_id")  <> "") Then 
  rs_read__MMColParam = Request.QueryString("news_id") 
End If
%>
<%
Dim rs_read
Dim rs_read_cmd
Dim rs_read_numRows

Set rs_read_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_read_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_tv_STRING
rs_read_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM news_update WHERE news_id = ?" 
rs_read_cmd.Prepared = true
rs_read_cmd.Parameters.Append rs_read_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rs_read__MMColParam) ' adDouble

Set rs_read = rs_read_cmd.Execute
rs_read_numRows = 0
%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.3.1 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
            body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
            }
        </style>
<body>
<div id="read">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#759DC4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="images/new_imgs/<%=(rs_read.Fields.Item("img_1").Value)%>" alt="" width="39" height="39" align="left" /><%=(rs_read.Fields.Item("news").Value)%></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<%
rs_read.Close()
Set rs_read = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: What script exactly? The JavaScript or the ASP code?

Comment: the asp code doesn't execute. it reads like a text files. i've configured my server correctly and other asp pages runs on it smoothly

Comment: ok i want to know is it good to link  a page in Jquery mobile for example <a href="good_page.asp">click here</a>, or it's always best to call (good_page.asp)it into a div?

Comment: Try ordinary link, yes.

Comment: or could it be how i've configureed my config.xml file